# jQuery best practice for $($(".elem")[0])?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to only use ONE dollar sign instead of doing this?

```
$($(".elem")[0]).hide()
```

I could use :first, but what about if I wanted the third or so:

```
$($(".elem")[2]).hide()
```

Comment: JavaScript uses zero-based arrays, therefore `$($(".elem)[3])` would return the *fourth* element, not the third.

Comment: Good catch.  Regardless, it looks like the answer is to use .eq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**.eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function

```
$(".elem").eq(3).hide()
```

> **Description**: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
>
> .eq( index )
>
> indexAn integer indicating the 0-based position of the element.

And

> .eq( -index )
>
> -indexAn integer indicating the position of the element, counting backwards from the last element in the set.

And it is `0 index based`, so third would be `.eq(2)`

Comment: The mistake's in the question, but that would return the *fourth* element matched by the selector, not the third.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, :eq

```
$('.test:eq(2)').hide(); //hides the third encounter of an element with class .test
```

There is also  :nth-child( x ) but it grabs a child element.

Read more,

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/